# AFNetworking response cache issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, afnetworking

I am sending GET request to server to getting json response. When i first do it i get some response but then i make changes in the database but still i get the same josn which i was getting.But on browser the json is updated on app it is not updated.I have used below code to make it work but nothing works for me.

```
  AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    [manager.requestSerializer setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];

    AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    [requestSerializer setValue:api_key forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;

    AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/html", nil];

    manager.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;

    [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)



     {

         NSLog(@"json is %@",responseObject);

         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)

     {

         [self activityIndicator:@"hide"];

         NSLog(@"Error: %@", operation.responseString);

     }];
```

I have tried **reloadignoringcachedata** but this does not work.

Comment: Please suggest something